# Google Nearby Places Doesn't Work Well - Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I use this query to check out my nearby places with my longlat;

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

I also use these place types;

```
https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types
```

When I search with 2000meter radius, nothing comes up to json. But when I search like 2000meter radius as visual on Google Map, 3-5 choices displays!

Do you know why this happens? (Api key works well, when I set radius as absurd number, it displays some results)

Comment: Are you doing this on a hybrid app? Or what is the reason behind using a queried URI?

Comment: No, native android app. I'm practising about 'nearby places'. There are several defined restaurants around my on Google Maps, but they don't display in my query.

Comment: Does restaurants that you search with 500 meter radius have 'cruise' in their names or descriptions? Why you use this keyword?

Comment: You just saved my life, thanks. I thought like its like Google protocol stuff and never mind it. Now it displays 19 restaurants with same meters. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The query searches for nearby places of type 'restaurant' within a 500m radius containing the word 'cruise'.

Look at the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) to know how to form a url according to your needs.

Nearby Search request is an HTTP URL

```
    https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/output?parameters
```

output may be either json or xml

Required Parameters

```
    key — Your application's API key. 
    location — The latitude/longitude around which to retrieve 
    place information. This must be specified as latitude, longitude.
    radius — Defines the distance (in meters) within which to 
    return place results.
```

For more information, read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search). Hope this helps you. Good luck.